# What did the Greek 'peripherein' carry?

Tags: etymology, greek

> [periphery (n.)](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=periphery&allowed_in_frame=0)
>       late 14c., "atmosphere around the earth," from Old French periferie (Modern French périphérie), from Medieval Latin periferia, from Late Latin peripheria, from Greek peripheria "circumference, outer surface, line round a circular body," literally "a carrying around," from peripheres "rounded, moving round, revolving," peripherein "carry or move round," from ***peri-* "round about"** (see [peri-](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=peri-&allowed_in_frame=0)) + ***pherein* "to carry"** (see [infer](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=infer&allowed_in_frame=0)). Meaning "outside boundary of a surface" attested in English from 1570s; general sense of "boundary" is from 1660s.

1. Am I right to guess: the modern definitions of this word (eg in English and French) lost the meaning of ***pherein* "to carry"** ? A boundary doesn't carry anything.

2. What did ***pherein*** carry? Or am I missing some figurative carriage?

Comment: It's figurative. _Bear_ in English is cognate, and one can speak of a planet bearing an atmosphere, though it's not common. _Bear_ means 'have; move; carry; be attached to' and can be applied in many situations, where it becomes fixed and "feels normal". (note that there is no bodily "feeling" involved in such a construction -- metaphor again).

Comment: Support the creation of a Greek stackexchange (now in the commitment phase) here:    https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/101509/greek-language

Comment: @NickNicholas It was closed, but see https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/117994/greek-language?referrer=HJCcFa4gZtNAO4eMXv3Z6Q2.

Comment: Ah yes. More of the curtness that makes Stack Exchange what it is, and then makes them scratch their heads about being regarded as unfriendly. Pfft.

Comment: @NickNicholas What can we do?

Comment: Welp, I'm touched to note that you're doing your bit by advertising the Area51 proposal in your user name. I... won't. If the new hurdle is to find where there'll be a critical mass of potential supporter in a preexisting forum, I'd suggest http://www.textkit.com . Then again, if there's already a textkit, why have a greek.stackexchange.com :-(

The other thing to do: angrily reject any calls to take Greek-specific questions off linguistics.stackexchange, given it's unlikely to get back up in a hurry.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect the meaning stems from wall-building, Herodotus has an example: "kata to teichos periphero" (teichos="wall"). I.e. originally it means "carrying [stones] to place them around something". Later the figurative meaning appeared, something around the walls, on the periphery of the city (and later - periphery in general).

Interestingly, my native Russian uses the exact same word morphologically (ob-nosit = peri-phero).